# Making Extension Methods/Constructors of a wrapper class Generic

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, wrapper

In a service (*that I cannot alter*) I have two object classes `Bar` and `Baz` with mostly similar properties (*but sadly NO, they don't derive from the same base class or inherit from the same Interface... yeah -- dumb*), as well as a dependency class related to their relative `BarQux` and `BazQux` properties:

```
public class Bar                          public class Baz
{                                         {
    public int ID { get; set; }               public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }          public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int BarQux { get; set; }           public int BazQux { get; set; }
    ...                                       ...
}                                         }

public class Qux
{
    public int ID { get; set; } // Corresponds to BarQux and BazQux
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In a WPF screen, I am binding a list of each type (`Baz` and `Bar`) to two seperate ListViews. I need each to have an additional `Selected` CheckBox column. To do so, I've created a wrapper class with the common properties, the additional `Selected` property, and a constructor for each:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Bar bar, Qux qux)
    {
        this.Active = bar.Active;
        this.FooQux = string.Format("{0} - {1}", qux.ID, qux.Name);
        ...
    }

    public Foo(Baz baz, Qux qux)
    {
        this.Active = baz.Active;
        this.FooQux = string.Format("{0} - {1}", qux.ID, qux.Name);
        ...
    }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string FooQux { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

To convert each collection of class `Baz` and `Bar` to collections of `Foo`, I created the following extension methods:

```
public static List<Foo> ToFoo(this IEnumerable<Bar> bars, IEnumerable<Qux> quxs)
{
    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

    foreach (Bar bar in bars)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo(bar, quxs.Single(qux => qux.ID == bar.BarQux));
        foos.Add(foo);
    }

    return foos;
}

public static List<Foo> ToFoo(this IEnumerable<Baz> bazs, IEnumerable<Qux> quxs)
{
    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

    foreach (Baz baz in bazs)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo(baz, quxs.Single(qux => qux.ID == baz.BazQux));
        foos.Add(foo);
    }

    return foos;
}
```

**Question:**

How do I make this generic?

**Theory, Implementation, and Error:**

1. Since the constructors are virtually the same besides the `Bar` and `Baz` parameters, can I somehow use generic type `T` to make one constructor and still grab the properties?

   ```
   public class Foo<T>
   {
       public Foo(T obj, Qux qux)
       {
           this.Active = obj.Active; // 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Active'...
           this.Qux = string.Format("{0} - {1}", qux.ID, qux.Name);
           ...
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Change the constructors to receive the whole collection of `Qux` objects and do the `quxs.Single(qux => qux.ID == object.ObjectQux)` logic there. Then make the extension methods into one generic method, something like the following.

   ```
   public static List<Foo> ToFoo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> objCollection, IEnumerable<Qux> quxs)
   {
       List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

       foreach (T obj in objCollection)
       {
           Foo foo = new Foo(obj, quxs); // The best overloaded method... has some invalid arguments.
           foos.Add(foo);
       }

       return foos;
   }
   ```
3. Both 1 and 2 combined? Anything I haven't thought of?

Comment: You might wanna check this out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: You can't modify the file or the you can't modify the class? For example you could implement a partial class. But then you would have to alter the original classes as being partial classes.

Comment: @ScottNimrod I can't modify any of the classes or files in the service such as the `Bar`, `Baz`, and `Type` classes. If I could I'd love to make the first two inherit from a base class or Interface - that would make this easier on my limited experience with generalizing things.

Comment: This look like a case of DTO object to/from BusinessObject kinda case. You can have full control on the businessObject implementation but the DTO object actually come from external service that "hard" to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have limited properties and the number of items in the list is also few then you can use `Reflection`. Since you will use this in WPF I would also suggest that the process be moved to a separate background thread.

Generic Foo

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(T obj, Qux qux)
    {
        //this.Active = obj.Active;

        var fooProps = GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
        var tProps = typeof(T).GetProperties()
            .Where(p =>
            {
                var w = fooProps.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == p.Name);
                return w != null;
            }).ToList();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in tProps)
        {
            var val = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
            fooProps.First(e => e.Name == propertyInfo.Name).SetValue(this, val);
        }
        this.FooQux = string.Format("{0} - {1}", qux.ID, qux.Name);
    }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string FooQux { get; set; }
}
```

Your extension methods

```
    public static IEnumerable<Foo<Bar>> ToFoo(this IEnumerable<Bar> bars, IEnumerable<Qux> quxs)
    {
        return bars.
            Select(bar => new Foo<Bar>(bar, quxs.Single(qux => qux.ID == bar.BarQux))).ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Foo<Baz>> ToFoo(this IEnumerable<Baz> bazs, IEnumerable<Qux> quxs)
    {
        return bazs.
            Select(baz => new Foo<Baz>(baz, quxs.Single(qux => qux.ID == baz.BazQux))).ToList();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<Qux> ToQuxes(this IEnumerable<BazQux> bazQuxs)
    {
        return bazQuxs.Select(b => new Qux(typeof(BazQux), b)).ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Qux> ToQuxes(this IEnumerable<BarQux> barQuxes )
    {
        return barQuxes.Select(b => new Qux(typeof(BarQux), b)).ToList();
    }
```

Similarly you can also convert your `BarQux` or `BazQux` into the non generic `Qux` class.

```
public class Qux
{
    public int ID { get; set; } // Corresponds to BarQux and BazQux
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Qux(Type type, object obj)
    {
        var ob = Convert.ChangeType(obj, type);

        var quxProps = GetType().GetProperties();
        var obProps = ob.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p =>
            {
                var w = quxProps.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == p.Name);
                return w != null;
            }).ToList();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in obProps)
        {
            var val = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
            quxProps.First(e => e.Name == propertyInfo.Name).SetValue(this, val);
        }

    }
}
```

You can then just call `ToFoo` extension method and voila you have a list of Foo.

You can also convert Foo to non-generic by using the logic of `Qux` class

Comment: Well written suggestion.  I am currently in the process of testing an idea along these lines, though I prefer your method of cycling through the properties. Not knowing much about reflection, I was curious if this would be too expensive and therefore not worth the time - the classes have 6 properties in common plus the `Qux` property and generally the number of objects being converted to `Foo` for any given client will range from a mere handful to possibly a few hundred. Thoughts? I'd like some time to test your suggestion and I'll get back to you afterwards.

Comment: Looking at the numbers of 6 properties and couple of hundred records the above solution is viable. The other benefit you have is that it is the client machine which is going to process using reflection. Had it been on the service end you might run into problems as the machine hosting the service will take a hit

Comment: Thanks for your input! I was not able to apply any of the changes to class `Qux` as that is also part of the service - but I didn't need them anyways. The generic class `Foo` worked out great. I posted an answer showing my exact usage to make the extension method also generic.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see any benefit of doing it this way.

If you are adamant about using generics you could do some type checking on the T like so:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(T obj, Qux qux)
    {
        var baz = obj as Baz;
        var bar = obj as Bar;

        Active = baz != null && baz.Active || bar != null && bar.Active;

        this.FooQux = string.Format("{0} - {1}", qux.ID, qux.Name);
    }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string FooQux { get; set; }
}
```

Or:

```
public static List<Foo> ToFoo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> objCollection, IEnumerable<Qux> quxs)
{
    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

    foreach (T obj in objCollection)
    {
        var baz = obj as Baz;
        var bar = obj as Bar;

        Foo foo = null;

        if(baz != null)
            foo = new Foo(baz, quxs.Single(qux => qux.ID == baz.BazQux));

        if(bar != null)
            foo = new Foo(bar, quxs.Single(qux => qux.ID == bar.BarQux));

        if(foo != null)
            foos.Add(foo);
    }

    return foos;
}
```

But this obviously isn't much better than what you already have and you would have to do some exception handling if T is not Bar or Baz (not shown) which would expose you to potential runtime failure. You could also use reflection but that would do the same.

What you are looking for unfortunately is not possible with C#. The only way you could get away with this is if interfaces were duck-typed a-la Golang, but this is not the case.

Comment: There is a valid point in implementing a wrapper. I had a scenario in which the application development was half way through when I was informed that there might be some more classes with same property names and types which also needs to taken care. It was not possible to write more constructors. So I went by reflection to take care of other classes to save dev time

Comment: My interest in generic implementation is for code reduction on duplicates and less future work should the service classes change. It may very well be the case that what I have is sufficient and generics would be less so - which I'm willing to accept - it's a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestions by Sandesh, the final results:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo() {}

    public Foo(T obj, IEnumerable<Qux> quxs, string quxPropName)
    {
        var fooProps = GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
        var tProps = typeof(T).GetProperties()
            .Where(p =>
            {
                var w = fooProps.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == p.Name);
                return w != null;
            }).ToList();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in tProps)
        {
            var val = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
            fooProps.First(e => e.Name == propertyInfo.Name).SetValue(this, val, null);
        }

        int id = (int)typeof(T).GetProperty(quxPropName).GetValue(obj, null);
        Qux qux = quxs.Single(q => q.ID == id);
        this.FooQux = string.Format("{0} - {1}", qux.ID, qux.Name);
    }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string FooQux { get; set; }
}
```

And the generic extension method:

```
public static List<Foo<T>> ToFoo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<Qux> quxs, string quxPropName)
{
    List<Foo<T>> foos = null;

    try
    {
        foos = list.Select(obj => new Foo<T>(obj, quxs, quxPropName)).ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
        foos = new List<Foo<T>>();
    }

    return foos;
}
```

And usage:

```
List<Foo<Bar>> bars = barCollection.ToFoo(quxCollection, "BarQux");
List<Foo<Baz>> bazs = bazCollection.ToFoo(quxCollection, "BazQux");
```

Comment: Add some exception handling as this approach also gives the scope for misuse as the `ToFoo` extension method can be used on other classes which implement `IEnumerable<T>` which you might want to prevent